# High program load, when killed program process, Linux doesn't go back to 0.5 normal load. Why?

Tags: linux, process, load-average

I ran a program that reached CPU load of 39.99, obviously more than my 4 core CPU can handle but why when I killed the program, (which is killed), the CPU load doesn't drop to 0.50 when I didn't turn the program on?

Also, I noticed that CPU load doesn't go down to 0.5 like instantly after a program is killed, you need to wait for it to go down slowly. Why is that?

Comment: Could the program interact with any running service that triggers other processes? Are you sure the remaining load in CPU is from same process?

Comment: "need to wait for it to go down slowly" -- Define "slowly". Usually you see averages for the past 1, 5 and 15 minutes (see `man 1 uptime`). To make such average go down "instantly" you need to add a large negative instantaneous value. Obviously the instantaneous load cannot be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably were reading was the 1, 5 or 15 minute load *average*.  This average would not go down instantaneously, but slowly, as the average load over the relevant time frame decreases.

After 15 minutes, the effect of the process that you killed would no longer affect any of the load averages.

Relevant manuals on your system:

- `man uptime`; displays the load averages and system uptime. This info is also displayed by `top` (along with much more data).
- `man getloadavg`; manual for a library function that returns the load averages from the system, used by `uptime` and `top`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "closing" a program just sends the kill signal to a child process related to the GUI or interface. But the main process (parent) is kept alive.

Try using `htop` to identify the main process and kill it.